# COLLADA from Sketchup is wrong colors

Tags: ros, rviz, collada-urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've update a robot description that previously used STL files (created from Solidworks) to use COLLADA files. Everything worked fine before, just wanted to make it prettier - i.e. add colors to the model.

I imported the STLs into SketchUp 8 using some plugin, and that went well. Upon adding correct colors, I exported to COLLADA using Sketchups builtin exporter. This is a screenshot of SketchUp with the correct colors:

[neobotix platform SketchUp http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7091/7402536638_8cf443cb26.jpg](http://www.flickr.com/photos/mrath/7402536638/)

Problem is that the COLLADA file comes up with wrong colors in Rviz:

[neobotix platform Rviz http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7096/7402561412_b8a810b481.jpg](http://www.flickr.com/photos/mrath/7402561412/)

I have tested the following:

- Use in model (Rviz) - Colors look too dark (see screenshot)
- Open in Meshlab - No colors
- Open in Preview.app on OSX - Colors look good

Please advice, and thank you in advance!

[COLLADA file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/38228546/neobotix_mp655.dae)

[SketchUp file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/38228546/neobotix_mp655.skp)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36825/collada-from-sketchup-is-wrong-colors/) by [mrath](https://answers.ros.org/users/975/mrath/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2012-06-19

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2012-06-20**:
can you attach the COLLADA file that produces wrong color?

**Comment by [mrath](https://answers.ros.org/users/975/mrath/) on 2012-06-25**:
Updated with attachments, kinda.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-06-25**:
I'm not sure, but does rviz use the colors or only works with textures?

**Comment by [mrath](https://answers.ros.org/users/975/mrath/) on 2012-06-25**:
I actually don't know. I just tried putting textures instead of color on some of the faces in sketchup, then re-exporting. It looks different, but not better, and textures does not show up in Rviz.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-06-25**:
I'm sure textures work, because I have used that.

**Comment by [mrath](https://answers.ros.org/users/975/mrath/) on 2012-06-25**:
From SketchUp as well, I presume? I guess I can make some textures which are just one plain color. Seems like an unnecessary hack though.

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2012-06-25**:
texture is not supported in collada_parser. I'll try if we can fix. BTW how did you visualize your model? I'm using [http://www.ros.org/wiki/collada_urdf/Tutorials/Working%20Directly%20with%20COLLADA] but it shows URDF failed model parse

**Comment by [mrath](https://answers.ros.org/users/975/mrath/) on 2012-08-07**:
I am pushing the robot URDF to the parameter server and visualizing in Rviz. The COLLADA files are just for visuals.

**Comment by [mcevoyandy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2166/mcevoyandy/) on 2012-08-24**:
you mentioned the parts were made in solidworks. Any reason you didn't use the solidworks collada export?  Works perfectly for me...  http://labs.solidworks.com/Products/product.aspx?name=colladaexport

**Comment by [mrath](https://answers.ros.org/users/975/mrath/) on 2012-09-10**:
I have not tried that, no, it seemed like to much trouble at the time. In the meantime I've lived with the bad model colors (remember this is only for visuals), but I might check that out at some point. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem fixed when upgrading from Fuerte to Hydro.

---

Originally posted by [mrath](https://answers.ros.org/users/975/mrath/) with karma: 100 on 2014-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0